# The Task.Run is not working because of Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Hi I am new to the asynchronous programming. I am following YouTube videos to learn. The `Task.Run` stops working if `Thread.Sleep` is used.

```
class App 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("app started");

        AsTask();

        Console.WriteLine("app Stopped");
    }

    public static async void AsTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("outside await");
        
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {         
            Console.WriteLine("Inside asyn fun");
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            Console.Write("async Task  Started");
            Console.Write(" #  Task  Completed");
            Console.WriteLine();
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: if what you are assuming is true, why doesnt neither prints "Inside asyn fun" ? Did you consider maybe is something about the async print in console?

Comment: On a side note, you really shouldn't sleep in a thread pool thread, which is what `Task.Run` runs the task on. Instead, use `Task.Delay`.

Comment: this is site usefull for learn Thread Sleep : https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-thread-sleep

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> the Task.Run stops working if thread.sleep used.

No, it doesn't.

However, you're not waiting for your task to complete in your `Main` method - your async method returns `void` rather than a `Task`, so you're basically saying "Start doing stuff, I don't care when it finishes." When your `Main` method completes, the process finishes - the thread pool (which is where your task will be executing) uses "background" threads, so they don't prevent the process from completing.

If you want to wait until your async method has actually finished, you should change this:

```cs
public static async void AsTask()
```

to

```cs
public static async Task AsTask()
```

... and make your `Main` method async so it can wait for the task:

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("app started");
    await AsTask();
    Console.WriteLine("app Stopped");
}
```